# P roblem in HmailServer

Tags: reboot

I have a windows dedicated server where we have Hmailserver to send out messages from the MS SQL Server 2008 database.

There was one problem, every week when the server rebooted, the mail was not working, my project manager used to fix it, now he is on 2 week vacation and its up to me to get this thing working, i tried the mssql dependency in add-on folder, but no use..

and then I found out hmailserver.ini file and started to meddle with it, i restarted the mail server. unfortunately, now its not even starting up. says invalid user name and password.

does anyone know how to deal with this?

sorry I do not even know what information I should provide which helps you..

Comment: i found a wizard to select default database, i enter all the credentials correctly, but the wizard comes up with an error message: Restarting the hMailServer service
Error: Database version could not be detected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dint know what was messed up but I gave up trying to fix it myself and called up the Tech Support guys who provide my dedicated server.. they fixed it for me.. took 2 days for them too but we finally got it working.